# Mmodify GPS tracker to accept two nmea inputs and gpsmarker to include a heading vector?

Tags: qgis, gps, assisted-gps

I use QGIS on a research vessel and wonder whether I could modify the QGIS 1.8.0 gpsinformation widget. I want to achieve two things.

1. Change the GPS marker to a boat shape which points in the direction of heading recieved as NMEA HDT sentence.
2. Add another marker from a second position feed which represents a towed underwater vehicle position. The underwater position is reported via a USBL modem which gives slant range and bearing to the target.